# Tools for visual complexity

Tags: visualization, complexity-theory

Could someone please recommend me some good tool to display the visual complexity. I am presenting Security Design Pattern which contains around 26 sub-patterns which are inter-related. I wish to display their relations in one diagram i.e. may be 26 blocks with the connected links shown by different color.

One site I came across is this - http://www.visualcomplexity.com/vc/ but it has pre-built applications. I am not allowed to customize or use any of these as per my requirement.

Please share if you are aware of any tool which can help me.

Comment: To display the visual complexity of what? Also, this kind of seems like a shopping question, and one not particularly appropriate for SO at that.

Comment: Also, the site you link to is just a catalogue of interesting information visualisation around the web. The individual items seem to have links to their sources. Look for the ones that look close to what you want, follow the links, and see if they mention what tools were used to make them?

Comment: I want to display my data and the diagram somewhat in this way - http://www.visualcomplexity.com/vc/project_details.cfm?id=585&index=90&domain=Knowledge%20Networks   I wish to show 13 pattern names in say color green and rest 13 say in color blue. This pattern uses petal like design to link/relate two types and in similar way I would link 2 patterns of different color.

Comment: Its bit difficult for me to explain exactly what I want, but assume that I want to make the same kind of diagram as in the link I shared in the above comment... This is a coded one, but I want some software which allows me to enter my data and displays the relationship or the similar diagram and this site doesn't mention the tool names they used to make them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graphviz is an open source graphing library which you may find useful. check out their wikipedia page for a list of applications which are based on Graphviz. I got my copy with php bindings as a pear package. Other bindings also exist.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org) is open and really ubiquitous.

The dot language is really simple and even Boost Graph Library (C++) interfaces with it. It comes with quite a number of relevant layout engines for this kind of diagram (`twopi` (radial) and `circo` (circular)).

I always feel it does have it's limits, but clearly the tool is so flexible that no-one seems to mind it: zillions of people use it.

See the gallery: http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php